Capcut webgl2 problem in ubuntu 23.04
for some reason, when i try to edit a video, capcut shows a error with the text "render error" so i refresh, the error happens again, i refresh again, until it shows my browser is not compatible, it tells me to turn on hardware acceleration yet it already is on

Are you sure you're using Ubuntu 23.04 ?

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
